# Wordpress logo not clickable back to home page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently creating a child theme and the logo is not clickable back to the home page where the code is there.

When I click view source it looks as though as it should be 
`<div class="tb-logo"> <a href="http://localhost:8080/wordpress-child" class="logo">
<img src="http://localhost:8080/wordpress-child/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/trim-logo.png" alt="name of image"></a></div>`. This is the header.php page

```
<header class="top-bar">

    <div class="tb-logo">
        <?php
        /**
         * Check if there is a uploaded logo
         */
        $kouki_logo = of_get_option( 'kouki_logo' );            
        if( $kouki_logo ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url()); ?>" class="logo">
                <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $kouki_logo ); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>">
            </a>                
        <?php else : ?>
            <h1><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>              


        <nav id="menu-child" class="t-lightweight" role="navigation">
            <span class="menu-detail"></span>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => '', 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ) ); ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>


</header>
```

So I'm not quite sure why it's not making the link clickable. I even tried hard coding it as `<a href="home page"><img src="image"></a>` but with no luck.

It only works when I don't load the child theme. The original looks like this

```
<header class="top-bar">

    <div class="tb-logo">
        <?php
        /**
         * Check if there is a uploaded logo
         */
        $kouki_logo = of_get_option( 'kouki_logo' );            
        if( $kouki_logo ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url()); ?>" class="logo">
                <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $kouki_logo ); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>">
            </a>                
        <?php else : ?>
            <h1><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="navigation-toggle-wrapper">         
        <a class="primary-nav-trigger" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <span class="menu-icon"></span>
        </a>    
        <nav id="menu" class="t-lightweight" role="navigation">
            <span class="menu-detail"></span>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => '', 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ) ); ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

</header>
```

So it's something to do with the menu classes but I don't know why?

Comment: Could you also paste the rendered HTML?

Comment: <div class="tb-logo">
       <a href="http://localhost:8080/wordpress-child" class="logo">
     <img src="http://localhost:8080/wordpress-child/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/trim-logo.png" alt="name">
    </a>    
     </div>

Comment: Well, the rendered URL is missing http://. Can you tell us what you have set as your Site URL in either your wp-config or in the CMS under Settings -> General?

Comment: If I had to guess, for the Site URL, you have it set to "localhost:8080/" which is incorrect. It needs to be have "http://" at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass a parameter in the path to home url. Try this:

```
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" class="logo">
            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $kouki_logo ); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>">
        </a>
```

Also, since the home page will forever be the (/) path, unless you wanted the logo to lead to a different page that will be dynamic, you can simple hard code it this way:

```
       <a href="/" class="logo">
            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $kouki_logo ); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>">
        </a>
```

Comment: Didn't make a difference unfortunately. It may be easier once the site is online for you to look at?

Comment: I think the '/' is optional and used for relative pathing.

Comment: Well, the home URL wouldn't always be / but it very well could be in his case. Additionally, WordPress loves its fully qualified URLs so you'd be deviating from that. I think the home_url is going to give you the benefit of pulling in what's stored in your wordpress settings.

Comment: the / gives you the initial path. It may be different in some sites, but I honestly haven't seen one that doesn't yet. I think it could be different in blogging sites that lead to the latest blog or latest news since they change periodically. I imagine this site is a regular site using wordpress with a regular path starting at /

Comment: as another alternative yet, it can be written /index/ or /home/ or /whatever/

Comment: I'm uploading the site online today so I'll put the link here once it is. It's a bit weird as when I click 'inspect element' the code is there but when I hover over the <a href=""> it shows it on the top left.

Comment: this is what I have in most of my 50+ sites 
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
       <img src="/img/LotusLogo.svg" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>">
</a>

Comment: @Gareth, don't post the link, as it will do nothing for us. We need to access or see the header.php or the function.php files. But having guest access (if you trust anyone here) is the best way becasue we will be able to see how you are permalinking etc

Comment: Try the alternative solution I added before you share your site

Comment: It works if I add this back in from the menu  <div class="navigation-toggle-wrapper">   
   <a class="primary-nav-trigger" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <span class="menu-icon"></span>
   </a> 
   <nav id="menu" class="t-lightweight" role="navigation">
    <span class="menu-detail"></span>
    <ul>
     <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => '', 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ) ); ?>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>

Comment: So the banner is clickable on mobile but not on computer, I have a feeling it's where the a link is located but I'm not sure why it would be anywhere other than the logo? The website is up and running if you want to check?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99521/discussion-between-lotusms-and-gareth).